# SQL Linq with contains items from list

Tags: c#, linq

here is my code:

```
CommissionCalculationDataContext dc = new CommissionCalculationDataContext();
CrossAppDataContext dc2 = new CrossAppDataContext();
List<Group_ADUser_Mapping> mapList = (from a in dc.Group_ADUser_Mappings where a.GroupID == '3' select a).ToList();
List<ADUser> userList = (from a in dc2.ADUsers where mapList.Contains(a.sAMAccountName) select a).ToList();  //doesnt work
```

The target is, I got a mapping list and then only need to get the User which are in this mapping list (by SAMAccountName)

Error is: Has OVerload problems....

So in fact I want to compare `Group_ADUser_Mappings.sAMAccountName` with `ADUser.sAMAAccountName`.

Comment: How it does not work?

Comment: so `Group_ADUSER_Mappings` has also a property `sAMAccountName` ?

Comment: Edited it with further information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
List<String> mapList = dc.Group_ADUser_Mappings.Where(x =>  x.GroupID == '3').Select(y => y.sAMAccountName).ToList();
List<ADUser> userList = dc2.ADUsers.Where(x => mapList.Contains(x.sAMAccountName)).ToList();
```

To avoid upper/lower case problems of `List.Contains`, you can filter afterwards. This should work (untested):

```
userList = userList.Where(x => mapList.Any(y => y.sAMAccountName == x.sAMAccountName)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just join the two entities and select your ADUser?

```
List<ADUser> userList = (from a in dc2.ADUsers 
    join b in dc.Group_ADUser_Mappings  on a.sAMAccountName equals b.sAMAccountName 
    where b.GroupID == "3" 
    select a).ToList();
```

Comment: Not 100% sure if you can join different data contexts -- if not then you could join it to the mapList you already have